# Create a checkbox that is automatically checked when other checkbox is already checked

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I am trying to build an UI for my algorithm, to handle some input parameters. Under that scope I am building a checkbox menu.

What I need to do is nest some checkboxes under some parent checkbox, so that when I click "Test", all checkboxes nested bellow can be automatically checked,  but then I want to have the ability to unlclick some of them (or parent) individually.

So, if I call them:

Test

-Subtest 1

-Subtest 2

I want to be able to check Test1 and have subtest 1 and subtest 2 checked, but to be able to override them, and unclick one of them, or even unclick Test and keep subtest1 and subtest2 clicked.

Keep in mind that test, subtest1 and suntest2 are referring to 3 individual objects, and test1 is not just a group shortcut.

I wrote this (it does not work)

```
{"Test 1",Checkbox[Dynamic[yesNoTest]]}
{"--Sub Test 1",
If[TrueQ[Dynamic[yesNoTest]],Checkbox[Dynamic[yesNoTestSub1]],

Checkbox[Dynamic[yesNoTestSub1]]
]}
{"--Sub Test 2",
If[TrueQ[Dynamic[yesNoTest]],Checkbox[Dynamic[yesNoTestSub1]],

Checkbox[Dynamic[yesNoTestSub2]]
]}
```

I do not know how to set a checkbox being "clicked" by default. My basic idea was to  test weather `yesNoTest` is True, and if so return 
`Checkbox[Dynamic[yesNoTestSub1]]` == True, else return it without knowing weather T or F and waiting for user to give input (as it is already)

Comment: How many sub-checkboxes do you expect to have?

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually there may be a case of 10 or so. Each of them will have a variable like yesNoTestSub1 that will be T/F. At a later on stage, I will use those variables to execute or not some parts of my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to use the second argument of `Dynamic`.

```
 DynamicModule[{yesNoTest = True
               , yesNoTestSub1 = True
               , yesNoTestSub2 = True},
         Grid @ 
         {
           {"Test 1", Checkbox[ Dynamic[yesNoTest, 
                      (    yesNoTest = #
                         ; If[#, yesNoTestSub1 = yesNoTestSub2 = True]
                      ) &]]
           }
           ,
           {"--Sub Test 1", Checkbox[Dynamic[yesNoTestSub1]]},
           {"--Sub Test 2", Checkbox[Dynamic[yesNoTestSub2]]}
         }
 ]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was seeking. Excellent use of # patterns. Still struggling to learn how to use it. Appreciate it. I added a variation in your code to automatically uncheck children boxes too, by adding: `If[#, yesNoTestSub1 = yesNoTestSub2 = True, 
 yesNoTestSub1 = yesNoTestSub2 = False]`